# How to make a text area appear in a Java JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jtextarea

I've searched the internet for solutions and I don't seem to find one that works for me... In case you're wondering, I'm new to Swing. So, here's the thing, `JButton` appears, but `JTextArea` doesn't. I don't know what to do to solve this... Help me out guys...

```
public class FrameCreation
{
    public JFrame createFrame(int width, int height, String name) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(name);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        return frame;
    }

    public JButton createButton(int width, int height, int xPos, int yPos, String text) 
    {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setBounds(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        button.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        return button;
    }

    public JTextArea createTextArea(int width, int height, int xPos, int yPos)
    {
        JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
        txt.setVisible(true);
        txt.setBounds(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        txt.setText("Help this poor JTextArea to appear on the frame...");
        return txt;
    }
}

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        FrameCreation mainFrame = new FrameCreation();
        JFrame f = new FrameCreation().createFrame(600, 600, "My Frame");
        f.add(mainFrame.createButton(100, 40, 10, 10, "Click me!"));
        f.add(mainFrame.createTextArea(200, 200, 390, 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer with actual code and output; now it's working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the frame.setVisible(true); from FrameCreation class, and add it f.setVisible(true);      in the end of main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FrameCreation mainFrame = new FrameCreation();
    JFrame f = new FrameCreation().createFrame(600, 600, "My Frame");
    f.add(mainFrame.createButton(100, 40, 10, 10, "Click me!"));
    f.add(mainFrame.createTextArea(200, 200, 390, 10));
    //This new line
    f.setVisible(true);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found your real problem; please don't use `frame.setLayout(null);`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242626/whats-wrong-with-the-null-layout-in-java) is a post explaining why null layout is bad. Instead I have used flow layout and it's working as it supposed to. Here is the code(I have changed them into two classes):

Main.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FrameCreation mainFrame = new FrameCreation();
        JFrame f = new FrameCreation().createFrame(600, 600, "My Frame");
        f.add(mainFrame.createButton(100, 40, 10, 10, "Click me!"));
        f.add(mainFrame.createTextArea(300, 300, 390, 10));
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

FrameCreation.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FrameCreation
{
    public JFrame createFrame(int width, int height, String name)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(name);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        return frame;
    }

    public JButton createButton(int width, int height, int xPos, int yPos, String text)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setBounds(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        button.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        return button;
    }

    public JTextArea createTextArea(int width, int height, int xPos, int yPos)
    {
        JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
        txt.setBounds(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        txt.setText("Help this poor JTextArea to appear on the frame...");
        return txt;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you add components to a visible GUI you need to tell the frame to repaint itself.

So you need to add:

```
f.revalidate();
f.repaint();
```

at the end of the main() method.

However, this is NOT the proper solution and is should not be used. You need to redesign your class.

> I'm new to Swing

There are too many things wrong with the code to list here. So instead I suggest you start by reading the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics.

Maybe start with the section on `How to Use Text Areas`. The `TextDemo` will show you how to better structure your code so that you:

1. create the Swing components on the Event Dispatch Thread.
2. create the JTextArea with a reasonable size
3. use layout managers.
4. pack() the frame and use setVisible( true ) AFTER all components have been added to the frame.